# Детект гипервизора (виртуальной машины)

Tags: c#

Каким образом програмно можно определить, что программа запущена на виртуальной машине (Hypervisor, Hyper-V)?

Comment: Интересует обнаружение простого гипервизора или такого, который активно пытается вас обмануть и не быть обнаруженным?

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, обычного гипервизора с дефолтными настройками.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Management;

using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem"))
{
  using (var items = searcher.Get())
  {
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
      string manufacturer = item["Manufacturer"].ToString().ToLower();
      if ((manufacturer == "microsoft corporation" 
        && item["Model"].ToString().ToUpperInvariant().Contains("VIRTUAL"))
      || manufacturer.Contains("vmware")
      || item["Model"].ToString() == "VirtualBox")
      {
            return true;
      }
    }
  }
}
return false;
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498371/how-to-detect-if-my-application-is-running-in-a-virtual-machine)